# Discrepancy of the length of stay between DS-160 and F-1 visa

Tags: usa, visa, student-visa, paperwork

In my I-20, the total course duration is mentioned as 7 years while in my PhD Assistantship award letter, my stipend is applicable till 4th year. Can you please tell me whether I should put 4 years or 7 years in my DS-160 as intended period of stay??

Moreover, my passport expires in Jan 2029 while according to my I-20 my course will end in August 2029.

Please advise me on what I should put in the DS-160 regarding intended period of stay.

Comment: What is your intended stay? Do you intend to stay for 4 years or for 7 years? You know better than us, I'm sure. Passport expiration is irrelevant.

Comment: I don’t know if it would be relevant, but if you intend to stay 7 years when your stipend only covers 4 years, how will you support yourself during those final 3 years?

Comment: F-1 visas are issued for no longer than 5 years in any case, and the expiry date on the visa does not limit the length of your stay in the US, so whether you indicate 4 or 7 years will make no more than a year's difference to the visa expiry and no difference at all to how long you can stay. I agree that how long you intend to stay is probably the best number to tell them.